# Add point when user logs in

Tags: php

so I am trying to test out adding points when a user logs in, but I have not been able to figure it out. It is logining the user in fine, but it is not adding the points or "rank." Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you for taking time to help

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = 'username'";
        } else {
            echo '<p> Sorry, logging in failed. </p>';
        }

        } else { 
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Edit: I added these lines but for some reason it is not connecting to the DB and I did put in the actual information obviously, not username, password etc.

```
if ($login) {
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db name')
or die('Error Connecting to Database on the SQL Server');
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$user_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = '$user_username'";
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you or if you have any issues with the answer. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating this line:

```
  $query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = 'username'";
```

to

```
$user_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = ".$user_username.";"
```

This needs to be done as you cannot simply pass in a string 'username'. PHP needs to know the value via a variable.

And also connect to SQL to update like

```
// use your credentials here instead of localhost, root, ''
 $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login')
        or die('Error Connecting to Database on the SQL Server');
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: More importantly, the query isn't being sent to the DB.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi So I am getting this error Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/adamadamadam01/public_html/login.php on line 23
Error Connecting to Database on the SQL Server

Comment: This is what I am doing, with the actual information of course      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db name')

Comment: @user3291224 My mistake, pardon me! I followed your syntax for double quotes and missed introducing variable in the query correctly. Please recheck. Also call the mysqli_query() after defining query

Comment: @DhruvJoshi so I was able to do it but I took out "mysql_real_escape_string." Idk if that's a big deal but I kept getting Mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @user3291224 Yes. you are correct on that part. I should have used Mysql_real_escape_string() instead, Importantly did it work w/o MySqli_real_escape_string()?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Yes it worked with out it but I am not sure if it is important to have in there

Comment: @user3291224 you can use Mysql_real_escape_string() instead, which accepts only one parameter. This is to escapes special characters in string and prevent SQL injection type attacks. See W3school for details

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the query execution:

```
if($login) {
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = 'username'");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace with this one, will solve issue.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

            $username = $user->login(Input::get('username')); // Get username of logged in user

        if($login) {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET rank = rank+5 WHERE username = '".$username."'";
            mysql_query($query); // change if you using mysqli
        } else {
            echo '<p> Sorry, logging in failed. </p>';
        }

        } else { 
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

missing to pass your `username` in this line.

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = 'username'";
```

correct it to

```
$username = "abc"; // assign value of you logged in user's username `abc` is the example
then user it as below.

    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET rank = rank + 5 WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

you simply pass a string `username`. you should pass it a variable that contains your username.

and also run the query in your page. you define the query not executed it.

Comment: there is no $username variable defined?

Comment: yes thats why i am giving the comment below my answer